# Edit Beard And Eyebrows Along Face

Tags: modeling, rigging, particles, hair

[image]

I'm trying to rig the face of my character. I have eyebrows, beard and face and they are different objects and beard and eyebrows has hair particle system. And now i want to make shape keys of face but I can only edit face at a time.

Merging beard and eyebrows make particle system disappear, so is there any way of rigging these all at once **so that if I move lips the beard moves along with lips and they also remain individual different objects.

[image]**

Answer (score 2):

In blender 2.80 you can edit several objects at a time.  When using shape keys, you will have to add a shape key to both objects, enter edit mode with both objects selected, and edit the shape key.  you can then assign the driver of your bone to both shape keys.

I hope this helps, please comment if you didn't understand something.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways of doing that, but first that comes to my mind is to give particle emitter mesh Shrink Wrap modifier with the head target. It will follow the face movement however you choose to influence it.